# Write all nginx redirection of the website pages in single location block

Tags: nginx

I want to write all the redirections of my website pages in one location block

This is what I have done so far

```
location /mywebsite {
    rewrite ^/mywebsite$ /index.php;
    rewrite ^/mywebsite/about$ /about.php;
    rewrite ^/mywebsite/services$ /services.php;
    rewrite ^/mywebsite/events$ /events.php;
    rewrite ^/mywebsite/events/(.*)$ /events.php?id=1 last;
}
```

but this does not work as intended.

Comment: what does not work ?

Comment: when I go to www.mywebsite.com/about it does not show about page

Comment: Can you try this ? `location = /mywebsite/about {
  return 301 http://new_website/about;
}`

Comment: when I write the location blocks separately for each page, it works. I am looking for a solution where I can write all the redirects in a single location  block.

Comment: Well, when you write these new redirects, for improving readability we place them separately in their respective blocks. Hence you can use Named Locations for that. From my limited experience, I don't think you can do it, as the location will vary, and you'll probably have to build a complex regular expression.

Comment: I tried like this also, but did not work
`location /mywebsite {
    index index.php
    rewrite ^/mywebsite/(\w)$ /$1.php break;
   rewrite ^/mywebsite/events/(.*)$ /events.php?id=1 break;
}`